# Can I use the Delphi XE2 Subversion integration with Subversion 1.7

Tags: delphi, svn, delphi-xe2

I have just migrated revision control systems to Subversion. We have chosen to use the latest version of Subversion, 1.7. When I switch to the history view in the Delphi editor an error occurs:

> The path 'path/to/my/project' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater working copy rooted at 'path/to/my/project'. Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this working copy.

Clearly the integration shipped with XE2 does not support Subversion 1.7. Does anyone know a workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It should be possible to install the latest version (use a Subversion client to get the latest sources from the SourceForge [SVN repository](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=341542)).

Edit (to clarify): "RAD Studio Version Insight" is the opensource project which provides the IDE Subversion integration. Its source code is maintained in a Subversion repository on SourceForge. So you can use any Subversion client to get the latest sources from that repository.

Currently the active maintainer of the project is [Uwe Schuster](http://www.bitcommander.de/blog/).

I've successfully updated my (trial) RAD Studio XE2 to use the current trunk (rev. 152). Here are the steps:

1. Check out the latest sources
2. Open the project group in the IDE, change library suffix to `160` in Project Options for each package
3. Delete or rename svn.dcp, svnui.dcp in `$(BDS)\lib\Win32\Release` directory
4. Rebuild all three packages (svn, svnui, svnide), close the IDE
5. Replace `svn160.bpl`, `svnui160.bpl`, `svnide160.bpl` in `$(BDS)\bin` directory
6. Replace Subversion client DLLs in `$(BDS)\bin\subversion` directory (I used [CollabNet Subversion Client](http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/) DLLs 1.7.1.7211)
7. Start the IDE

Comment: I have svn 1.7 in the form of Tortoise. It's the Delphi integration about which I know nothing.

Comment: Yes, then you can use Tortoise to get the latest sources of "RAD Studio Version Insight", rebuild it and install it in your IDE.

Comment: I've checked out that project at the trunk but it fails to build. The error is weird. At `FSvnClient.AddToChangeList` the compiler complains that there is no such method. I can see the method clearly in the source code. I'm building in Delphi XE2 and it is slightly worrying that the packages are all numbered 150.bpl. In short, I'm completely at sea!

Comment: Perhaps the easiest is to try the Beta 7.1 of "Version Insight Plus" [from Uwe's blog](http://www.bitcommander.de/blog/index.php/2011/11/22/verins-plus-7-1/) - it comes with an installer. I haven't tried it.

Comment: With Version Insight Plus Beta 7.1 I'm getting the same error message as in my question. The call stack ends in DelphiSVN160.dll which is part of Version Insight Plus. Do you know if I need to replace the history IDE package or something?

Comment: Or perhaps what I need is a 32 bit version of the subversion client (my Tortoise is 64 bit).

Comment: Yes, it looks like I need to update svn libs too: http://www.bitcommander.de/blog/index.php/2011/06/01/verins-svn-dlls/  So please stand down for the moment!  ;-)

Comment: Thanks again. I've got this working now thanks to your help. And thanks also to Uwe. Once I read far enough down his blog, I found all that I needed to piece it all together.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else who encounters the problem, and thanks to TOndrej and Uwe, here is exactly what I did to get integration of svn 1.7 in XE2. I expect the same would work in XE.

- Install [Version Insight Plus Beta 7.1](http://www.bitcommander.de/blog/index.php/2011/11/22/verins-plus-7-1/).
- Install the [win32svn](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/) client.
- Point the Delphi IDE at the appropriate svn client with a registry setting in   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\9.0\Subversion`. Add a `REG_SZ` value named `SvnDllDir`, whose value is the `bin` directory of the win32svn client, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin` in my case. For XE this would be `...\BDS\8.0\...`.

Comment: If you install the latest TortoiseSVN and VersionInsightPlus Beta 7.1 that is actually all you need.

Comment: @Stefan I don't think so. You need the registry key. And my Tortoise is 64 bit, and has DLLs with a different naming convention from that assumed by Version Insight.

Answer (score -2):

another choice: you can create your repository with option --compatible-version ,it can make you create repository for old version.try "svnadmin help create" to get more information.you old version subversion can work well in rad studio