# How can I remove double SVN integration menu's in the Delphi IDE?

Tags: delphi, svn, delphi-xe

An image says more than thousand words in this case:[image]

As you can see, I have 2 Subversion menu entries in the Project Manager.
How can I remove those bogus second menu entries?

Environment: Windows 8.1 x64, Delphi XE, CollabNet 1.8, TortoiseSVN

**EDIT**

I got this behaviour after following instructions from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8447290/800214) to get the integration working with SVN 1.8.

Comment: Did you install the third party svn add in too? VersionInsight is its name IIRC.

Comment: Yes it is installed  under c:\program files (x86)\versioninsight (came with delphi installation I believe?)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: your comment was spot on! I renamed this folder and now I only have 1 menu entry. Thank you very much!

Comment: But now I am a bit confused, does this mean I don't need the VersionInsight software at all?? (I was reading this post : http://stackoverflow.com/q/8447290/800214)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it you have installed both the built in integration, and third party integration from VersionInsight. It seems that you want to use the latter and so need to remove the built-in integration. I suspect that you'll be able to do that with a repair/modify install from the Programs area of the control panel.

Comment: Are you suggesting to keep VersionInsight in favor of the built-in integration? As it seems now, it is VersionInsight that is not working.

Comment: Clearly you'll want to keep something that works. The question of mine that you linked to was asked because XE2 built in did not work with svn 1.7. VersionInsight fixed that. I'd expect VersionInsight to work when installed correctly and fed the correct svn dlls.

Comment: Well at the moment, the built-in integration works, but has clearly less features than the Version Insight client (no blame, no svn Icons in project manager, ...). What sucks is that I can't find where I can download the latest Version Insight software...

Comment: I think VersionInsight dev has stopped. I think you may need to get it from the source repo and build.

Comment: I see, but the thing is that the repo is just an updated copy of the integrated client (and has nothing to do with versioninsight plus :( ).

Comment: Are you sure. I'm looking at this: https://sourceforge.net/projects/radstudioverins/

Comment: Yes, that one. Do you have by chance the Version Insight plus beta installer somewhere and could you provide it to me? (I don't know if there is PM functionality on SO)

Comment: I do have an installer. It won't do 1.8 I think though. I can't get to it for a few days as I am away from the office.