# Show Subversion differences directly in Delphi IDE editor

Tags: delphi, svn, version-control, delphi-xe5

Are there some plugins that allow Subversion diff to be displayed directly in the Delphi IDE editor with different colored backgrounds?

The idea is to look at differences while debugging.

**Update**

When I use the "History" tab, I get an error:

> This client is too old to work with the working copy at 'C:\work\Projects\MyProject' (format 31). You need to get a newer Subversion client. For more details, see http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#working-copy-format-change.

When I set the path to Tortoise SVN client as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181376#21183259), I get another error:

> 2 Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden: libapr-1.dll.

When I set the path to where this file exists, I get the first error message again.

Comment: The History tab at the bottom of the editor should already do that. Help says "If the current file is under version control, all types of revisions are available in the History Manager."

Comment: @Brian already in Delphi XE5? Wasn't that added later?

Comment: I see the same sentence in the online help for XE5 : http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/History_Manager

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8447386/62576 for information about how to upgrade the IDE's SVN version. The post is written about XE2, but the information is still relevant.

Comment: You need to have the 32-bit subversion libraries on your machine (in the machine ’path’). The client lib from collabnet works: http://www.collab.net/downloads/svn-other

Comment: @R. Hoek: I have just uninstalled the client from CollabNet :) The reason was that it wasn't up to date and couldn't do advanced renamings.